# Can't make my first kubernetes deployment work

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes. I am trying to deploy my first application. Can someone tell me why the following YAML is not working?

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  labels:
    name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: app-service
            port: 
              number: 8012
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/abc"
        backend:
          service:
            name: app-service
            port: 
              number: 8012
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: learning-app-pod
  ports:
  - port: 8012
    targetPort: 3000
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: learning-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: learning-app-pod
  
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: learning-app-pod
    
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: learning-app-container
  
        image: quay.io/some_test_stuff/frontend:v1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

I get error when I visit localhost or localhost/abc.

Thanks,

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: No error but it is not working either, I.e. we I got to localhost/abc, it looks like nothing is running

Comment: Are you trying this on browser? you need a mapping in your `/etc/hosts` with the external IP address of your ingress service

Comment: curl http://localhost/abc
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Comment: what's the output of `kubectl get ing`?

Comment: Here is the output
No resources found.
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "ingress-nginx" not found

Comment: edited my comment. can you run that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252465/discussion-between-ali-salehi-and-amila-senadheera).

Comment: I get 
NAME        CLASS     HOSTS       ADDRESS                           PORTS     AGE
myingress   <none>    localhost   router-default.apps-crc.testing   80        64m

and when I go to HTTP://router-default.apps-crc.testing

I get 

Application is not available
The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.